# ORM expr evaluate empty string

Tags: symfony

I have been using and still learning query expr(). I have a complex query where I cannot use if first to check if a parameter is '' - empty string.
I have to check it inside andX with nested orX using something like:

```
->andWhere($expr->orX($expr->eq(':sid', ''), $expr->neq('s.id', ':sid')))
```

Note: I know this line can be done by using if check first, I am using it just for an example, I got error says:

```
Error: Expected Literal, got ' OR '
```

I really need to compare empty string inside expr(), how?

Comment: If `s.id` is rather `NULL`, you can try with [$expr->isNull()](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

Answer (score 19):

Because `''` is not an empty string. It's nothing and so it evaluates to nothing in DQL/SQL. Normally doctrine expects an named parameter. Either you create one to get quoted empty string or supply an empty string quoted by yourself.

Named parameter:

```
$qb->expr->eq('foo', ':foo');
$qb->expr->setParameter('foo', '');
```

quoted by yourself:

```
$qb->expr->eq('foo', "''");
```